# Converting Rust macro types into expressions

Tags: macros, rust

I'd like to assume a given type implements some trait (e.g. `Default`) with a method (e.g. `default()`). I want to call that method and store its value into a local variable. Here is a general idea of it:

```
macro_rules! get_default {
    (  $x:ty = $alias:ident ) => {
        let $alias = $x::default();
    };
}

fn main() {
    // get_default!(i32 = z); 
    // println!("get_default! {:?} ", z);
    println!("i32 default {:?} ", i32::default());
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=macro_rules!%20get_default%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(%20%20%24x%3Aty%20%3D%20%24alias%3Aident%20)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20%24alias%20%3D%20%24x%3A%3Adefault()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20get_default!(i32%20%3D%20z)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22get_default!%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%20%22%2C%20z)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22i32%20default%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%20%22%2C%20i32%3A%3Adefault())%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0).

When I try that I get an error:

```
error: expected expression, found `i32`
 --> <anon>:3:22
  |>
3 |>         let $alias = $x::default();
  |>                      ^^
```

I understand it's because it expects an expression, but I want to limit input to types only. Is there a way to turn `$x` from `ty` to `expr`, or a way to call a method on a type (even if it's potentially missing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were almost there. You can hint the expected default type to the compiler and then just use the [universal function call syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ufcs.html):

```
macro_rules! get_default {
    (  $x:ty = $alias:ident ) => {
        let $alias = <$x as Default>::default();
    };
}

fn main() {
    get_default!(i32 = z); 
    println!("get_default! {:?} ", z);
    println!("i32 default {:?} ", i32::default());
}
```

([Playground link](https://gist.github.com/ca4f7578230981a3f9b22b979201632a))

The key bit is this:

```
let $alias = <$x as Default>::default();
```

This casts `$x` to the `Default` trait and then invokes the `default()` method, as you needed.

You can also use a shorthand when you don't need to disambiguate between traits:

```
let $alias = <$x>::default();
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=283d04feeb1832c6fa5be5f1f2ec3750))

### More General Usage of UFCS

Using UFCS as shown above, you can disambiguate between traits that implement the same methods. This is the '[angle-bracket form](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ufcs.html#angle-bracket-form)' which is useful if the `default()` method is implemented in two traits.

In this specific scenario, you can also use UFCS more specifically, like so:

```
let $alias: $x = Default::default();
```

That alone provides enough information for Rust to infer the correct `impl`.

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=283d04feeb1832c6fa5be5f1f2ec3750&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Comment: May want to add that the *direct* way of doing this is `<$x as Default>::default()`.  In general, you can use `<Type>` to refer to types in paths that aren't directly valid as paths (which include macro substitutions, `[_]`, and `&T`).

Comment: Yes, DK solution is actually what I was looking for, because I wanted a more general solution, than just works with `Default`.

Comment: @DK Expanded with a section on your suggested methods. If there are any details I've missed that you feel are important, feel free to suggest them.

Comment: @Aurora0001: The answer I was looking for was `<$x as Default>`, note I said e.g. `Default`. If trait doesn't return `Self`, I can't use `let $alias: $x = Default::default();` I used `Default` as example because it's the first trait that popped to my mind.

Comment: @DanielFath: updated my answer to be more like what you wanted and fixed the playground links that were outdated.